# How can I change the line style of the indent guides?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017 comes with [built-in support for indent guides](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/03/08/optimize-your-productivity-with-net-in-visual-studio-2017-2/):

> Indent Guides ­– dotted, gray vertical lines act as landmarks in code to provide context within your frame of view. You may recognize these from the popular Productivity Power Tools.

Here's a screenshot demonstrating this:

[image: VS2017 screenshot of indent guides]

I've been using [Steve Dower's Indent Guides extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveDowerMSFT.IndentGuides) for years now, which supports changing the line style:

[image: VS2015 screenshot of indent guides and line style options]

Is it possible to change the line style in VS 2017? I had a look in the Options but couldn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From everything I can see, there is unfortunately no way to do this, aside from using a different extension. If you use ctrl+Q to search (FYI, ctrl+Q is a great feature that many people don't notice), and search for "guide" you will see it only returns a single configuration option:

Text Editor -> General -> Show structure guide lines

So apparently, all you can do is turn it on or off and change the color of the lines. This can be done by going to Environment -> Fonts and Colors and looking for "Structure Guide Lines."

Comment: For the benefit of people like me who came here looking to change the colour (not the style), the colour option is "Structure Guide Lines"

Comment: I didn't see that setting, I updated the answer to reflect that you can change the color.

Comment: Exactly! The  Environment -> Fonts and Colors and looking for "Structure Guide Lines." is defaulted to White background. Interestingly VS2017RC was defaulted to a gray color.

Comment: note that this setting doesn't exist in the VSCE version.